# how to open dialog Material ui from parent react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have parent component which has a drawer and some IconButton, I want when I click on the IconButton first the dialog on child component load then if accept the dialog close and rest of the child load
**parent component**

```
<Child sendId = {id} OpenDialog={true}/>
```

**child component**

```
const handleClose = () => {
    OpenDialog = false
};
return 
    OpenDialog ? 
        <Dialog open={OpenDialog} onClose={handleClose} >
            some Content
        </Dialog>
    : <div>
        rest of child componet
        </div>
```

but it always open, I want to if I close the doalog and click on parent `<Child  ...` the dialog open again

Answer (score 0):

You have to control the state of the dialog in the parent component

**parent**

```
const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
<Child sendId = {id} openDialog={openDialog} setOpenDialog={setOpenDialog} />
```

**child**

```
const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false)
};

return 
    OpenDialog ? 
        <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleClose} >
            some Content
        </Dialog>
    : <div>
        rest of child componet
        </div>
```